# Speed of object[property]

Tags: javascript, performance, set

I want to keep eye on "which objects already were processed" by pushing them into some set.
As there is no type Set in JavaScript, I'm gonna use Object, like stated at [Mimicking sets in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript)
So the question is: **does this *dictionary-check* depend on amout of objects already pushed into my Set object? Is it O(N) or O(1)?**

Comment: jsperf.com would be the place to find this out

Comment: You could [create a jsPerf test case](http://jsperf.com/) to measure the speed differences between browsers and devices.

Answer (score 1):

The answer varies across the JS engine, definitely. Regarding V8, the check speed does depend on the amount of objects (== "Set" object property count) but it's still O(1). Otherwise no considerable web application would work fast enough.

Regarding the SO question you reference, do NOT use `if ("foo" in A)` to check the element presence, if possible - this will traverse the entire prototype chain, so you will get a performance impact and most probably find a lot of objects that should not be there (like `toString`). Use `A.hasOwnProperty("foo")` whenever possible.

Comment: Regarding the SO question you reference, do NOT use `if ("foo" in A)` to check the element presence, if possible - this will traverse the entire prototype chain, so you will get a performance impact and most probably find a lot of objects that should not be there (like `toString`). Use `A.hasOwnProperty("foo")` whenever possible.

Comment: You may push your comment into the answer ) Looks like people find it more useful, than the first part.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, it's 10 times faster use `if(A['foo'])` instead  `hasOwnProperty`, look this perf test: http://jsperf.com/in-vs-hasownproperty-2/2

Comment: @MartinBorthiry: the check you suggest has a VERY limited use (no objections to the speed difference, obviously). Check `if ({"A": ""}["A"]) console.log("FOO")` or `if ({"A": 0}["A"]) console.log("FOO")` in your DevTools/Web Inspector.

Comment: Of course Alex, but I think that for Nakilon question is enough `obj.processed=1`