# Check if duplicate array pairs exist using underscore only

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am wondering how I can check if a duplicate pair of values in an array exist as part of a larger array in javascript. You can see there is a duplicate pair of `[1,2]` - so the function should just return `true`. i.e

```
var arr = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10], [11,12], [13,14], [1,2]]
```

I have tried using this logic which gives me a clean array and a "true"

```
var unique = [];
var done = []; var dup = false;
for(var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    var myStr = arr[x].toString();

    if(done.indexOf(myStr) != -1) {
        // val already exist, ignore
        dup = true;
        continue;
    }

    done.push(myStr);
    unique.push(arr[x]);
}
```

But I was wondering if there is something more elegant using Underscore ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest way would be to use `_.uniq` and `JSON.stringify`:

```
function unique(arr) {
    return _.uniq(arr, JSON.stringify).length === arr.length;
}
```

But that doesn't short-circuit, so it's somewhat slow compared to the other ways you could do it. [Tomalak's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16762040/464744) second function should be faster.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is a lot nicer than `.toString()` or `.join()`. +1 PS: Hah, we implemented the same pure JS solution... :) I'd just be careful with the use of `in`. `hasOwnProperty()` returns `false` for the string `"length"`, `in` would return `true`.

Comment: The second solution doesn't actually work if an array contains strings that look like joined arrays like `"1,2"` etc. Remember, object keys are always strings! `stringify` is much better as it carries type and uses it for comparisons.

Comment: @thg435: Well, if I were to fix it, then you'd basically get [Tomalak's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16762040/464744) answer ;)

Comment: @Blender: he's making the same mistake: `containsDuplicates([[1,2], "1,2"])` returns true.

Comment: @thg435: From what I understood, OP is just working on arrays of arrays of numbers, so it would work in his case. But yes, that would be a problem if there were mixed data types.

Comment: @thg435 Yes, I was making assumptions about the input. Plus I did not think of JSON.stringify. I shall fix that.

Comment: yeah the inputs will be integers - not strings. But it would be great to account for both for completeness :)

Comment: @Andy: Yep. If the array without duplicates has the same number of elements as the array with duplicates, then no duplicates were ever there.

Comment: also is there any way to modify it so I can check for a specific duplicate ?

Comment: @Andy: What's a specific duplicate?

Comment: sorry - so I mean - I am pushing new values into the array. What I wanted to do was check if that new `[1,2]` value I just pushed already exists and skip it ? the value would still remain in the array however

Comment: @Andy: Keep a dictionary of already-present elements (similar to what Tomalak is doing) and use that.

Comment: @Blender - thanks for the response. Bit unsure how to just get a result for the most recent ? i.e. like `containsDuplicates(arr, newPair)` - which is like `containsDuplicates(arr, [5,6])` ? appreciate any help

Comment: @Andy: you're looking for Sets. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7958292/989121 etc

Comment: @thg435 - is that a bit overkill ? what about something like - http://jsbin.com/oreval/5/edit ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `uniq` seems like a good fit

```
function containsDuplicates(arr) {
  return arr.length !== _.uniq(arr, function (item) { return item.toString(); }).length;
}
```

You should use Blender's version of this function. It's shorter and safer.

---

BTW, your code should look more like this:

```
function containsDuplicates(arr) {
    var index = {}, i, str;

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // you could use arr[i].toString() here, but JSON.stringify()
        // is a lot safer because it cannot create ambiguous output.
        str = JSON.stringify(arr[i]);
        if (index.hasOwnProperty(str)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            index[str] = true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note that this is probably more efficient than the underscore one-liner.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer I'm pretty sure it works. How did you test it?

Comment: in my browser, seems like Blender fixed it for you now

Comment: @Willem Darn copy/paste mistakes. Yes, that was it.

Comment: @Tomalak - thanks for the response. Is there a way to check whether the latest pair pushed to the array is a duplicate ? Not just whether "any duplicate" exists ? i.e. like `containsDuplicates(arr, newPair)` - which is like `containsDuplicates(arr, [5,6])`

Comment: @Andy If you ask me like this... yes, there is a way to do this. :)

Comment: @Tomalak - apologies if did something wrong :) I ended up trying to do something like this - http://jsbin.com/unasem/2/edit. Its sort of messy but it works. Would REALLY TOTALLY appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: @Andy Well, that's messy indeed. Can you explain what you are trying to do? Seems like you actually want something like `arr.pushIfNotExists(value)`, could that be?

Comment: @Tomalak - actually all I am trying to do is to return whether the pair of `[1,2]` exists in an array of arrays. Its difficult as there isnt any underscore etc function to do this where its an array of arrays ? http://jsbin.com/unasem/4/edit - this works but isnt great

Answer (score 2):

Although `stringify` is *the* answer most of the time, it still has its issues, for example `{"x":1,"y":2}` and `{"y":2,"x":1}` are considered different. If you need a 100% accurate comparison, there's no other way as to store already processed objects and deep compare them (luckily, underscore provides an utility for this).

```
uniq2 = function(xs) {
    return _.reduce(xs, function(result, x) {
        if(!_.any(result, _.partial(_.isEqual, x)))
            result.push(x);
        return result;
    }, []);
}
```

Test:

```
var arr = [[1,2], [3,4], "1,2", "[1,2]", [1,2], {x:1,y:2}, {y:2,x:1}]
console.log(uniq2(arr))
// [[1,2],[3,4],"1,2","[1,2]",{"x":1,"y":2}]
```

This is going to be quadratic in the worst case, but there's no other way.