# Caching and walking an ArrayController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `Phone` model. I want to cache all phones on my application:

```
cachePhones : function () {
    this.set('phones', this.Phone.find());
},
```

And get the countries for which I have available phones:

```
getCountries : function () {
    var phones = this.get('phones.content');
    var countries = new this.dataSet(), country;
    console.log('phones=%o', phones.length);
    for (var index = 0, length = phones.length; index < length; index++) {
        country = phones[index].record.get('country');
        console.log('Adding %o', country);
        countries.add(country, true);
    }
    console.log('countries=%o', countries.keys());
    return countries.keys();
},
```

([`dataSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7958422/647991) is just a set implementation in javascript)

I am not sure this is the right way to walk the `ArrayController`:

- do I really need to access the `content`?
- do I really need to access `record`?

This feels like hacking around my way in the ember internals. I have tried before this:

```
var phones = this.get('phones');
var countries = new this.dataSet(), country;
for (var index = 0, length = phones.length; index < length; index++) {
    country = phones[index].country;
    countries.add(country, true);
}
```

But it was not working at all. What is the canonical way of walking an `ArrayController`?

Comment: You can use Ember.Set.create(); instead of new this.dataSet();. Ember have your own Set implementation ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this? Normally you should always be fine with using the functional methods Ember offers for its collections.

```
var phones = this.get('phones');
var countries = new this.dataSet(), country;
phones.forEach(function(phone, index){
  country = phone.get("country");
  countries.add(country, true);
});
```

Comment: Looks much cleaner than my implementation. I'll try that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Besides @mavilein correct answer one thing worth mentioning is that if you have a model like `App.Phone` then after you do `App.Phone.find()` and the records are fetched, your `Store` has already a cache which you can consult with `App.Phone.all()` this will not make another request but gives you the records available in the `Store`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if I do not know if the phones have already been requested? Can I access `App.Phone.all()`, and a `App.Phone.find()` will be done automatically?

Comment: no, `.all()` only retrieves the already fetched records if any, see here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L848