# javascript - find unique objects in array based on multiple properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find unique objects from array based on 2 properties as below. When "class" and "fare" match, I need to pull out unique values and get them in results array.

Source:

```
var arr = [{class:"second", fare: "a"}, 
 {class:"second", fare: "b"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"second", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "c"}
]
```

Expected result:

```
var result = [{class:"second", fare: "a"},
 {class:"second", fare: "b"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "c"}
]
```

I looked over in SO and was able to find answer which is filtered based on one property ([Create array of unique objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773778/create-array-of-unique-objects-by-property)), but couldn't find which could do based on 2 properties.

Comment: I think there would be more willingness to help if you showed your own attempt at a solution. You don't *have* to take answers from online; even a long-winded solution based on mild knowledge of object key access might get you thinking about the important parts.

Comment: `class` is an ES6 reserved word. Use 'kind', 'type' or any other alternative.

Comment: @Katana314 - Well, I tried couple of things but then removed that code eventually. Anyway, will try to pos that.

Comment: @alex030293 - yeah, i agree. i just used it for demo purpose, am actually not using class

Comment: @alex030293 There is no problem whatsoever using `class` as a property name.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could build a combined key for the hash table and filter the given array.

```js
var arr = [{ class: "second", fare: "a" }, { class: "second", fare: "b" }, { class: "first", fare: "a" }, { class: "first", fare: "a" }, { class: "second", fare: "a" }, { class: "first", fare: "c" }],
    result = arr.filter(function (a) {
        var key = a.class + '|' + a.fare;
        if (!this[key]) {
            this[key] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The same without (mis)using `thisArg` of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var array = [{ class: "second", fare: "a" }, { class: "second", fare: "b" }, { class: "first", fare: "a" }, { class: "first", fare: "a" }, { class: "second", fare: "a" }, { class: "first", fare: "c" }],
    seen = Object.create(null),
    result = array.filter(o => {
        var key = ['class', 'fare'].map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        if (!seen[key]) {
            seen[key] = true;
            return true;
        }
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey, just one doubt, why do we need "Object.create(null)" here?

Comment: that generates a really empty object without prototypes, like `toString` or so.

Comment: so would that be needed here

Comment: actually not, but i do not know your data.

Answer (score 19):

Using a combined key and a Map

```js
const array = [
 { class: "second", fare: "a" }, 
 { class: "second", fare: "b" }, 
 { class: "first", fare: "a" }, 
 { class: "first", fare: "a" }, 
 { class: "second", fare: "a" }, 
 { class: "first", fare: "c" }
];

console.log(unique(array, ['class', 'fare']));

function unique(arr, keyProps) {
 const kvArray = arr.map(entry => {
  const key = keyProps.map(k => entry[k]).join('|');
  return [key, entry];
 });
 const map = new Map(kvArray);
 return Array.from(map.values());
}
```

Comment: Tamo, can you add explanation on how this is working? I am a little confused on the `.join` part.

Comment: `join` converts an array to a string while inserting the separator between items `|`. It's creating a string based on the values of the keyProps. `second|a`, `second|b`, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 8):

Hey you can use this method

```
const unique = (arr, props = []) => [...new Map(arr.map(entry => [props.map(k => entry[k]).join('|'), entry])).values()];

const array = [
    {
        class: 'second',
        fare: 'a', 
    },
    {
        class: 'second',
        fare: 'b', 
    },
    {
        class: 'first',
        fare: 'a', 
    },
    {
        class: 'first',
        fare: 'a', 
    },
    {
        class: 'second',
        fare: 'a', 
    },
    {
        class: 'first',
        fare: 'c',
    },
];

const newArr = unique(array, ['class', 'fare']);

console.log(newArr) // [{ class: 'second', fare: 'a' }, { class: 'second', fare: 'b' }, { class: 'first', fare: 'a' }, { class: 'first', fare: 'c' }]
```

Answer (score 4):

short way to solve the above problem though it is a very old thread and maybe it might help someone in the future.

```
const array = [
  { class: "second", fare: "a" }, 
  { class: "second", fare: "b" }, 
  { class: "first", fare: "a" }, 
  { class: "first", fare: "a" }, 
  { class: "second", fare: "a" }, 
  { class: "first", fare: "c" }
];

const uniqueObjects = new Set();

array.forEach(arr => uniqueObjects.add(JSON.stringify(arr)));

console.log(uniqueObjects.entries())
```

Comment: `const array = [
  { class: "second", fare: "a" }, 
  { class: "second", fare: "b" }, 
  { class: "first", fare: "a" }, 
  { class: "first", fare: "a" }, 
  { fare: "a", class: "second" }, 
  { class: "first", fare: "c" }
];`
your code doesn't work with this array

Answer (score 2):

Like most answers, convert to a map with keys being a concatenation of the values, then back to an array. This one uses [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const array = [
  { class: "second", fare: "a" }, 
  { class: "second", fare: "b" }, 
  { class: "first", fare: "a" }, 
  { class: "first", fare: "a" }, 
  { class: "second", fare: "a" }, 
  { class: "first", fare: "c" }
];

console.log(unique(array, ['class', 'fare']));

function unique(arr, keyProps) {
  return Object.values(arr.reduce((uniqueMap, entry) => {
    const key = keyProps.map(k => entry[k]).join('|');
    if (!(key in uniqueMap)) uniqueMap[key] = entry;
    return uniqueMap;
  }, {}));     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another several variations of extracting a unique array of objects based on arbitrary array of their fields, tested on performance:

**Always the best by performance, *uses recursive function***

```js
const arr = [{class:"second", fare: "a"}, 
 {class:"second", fare: "b"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"second", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "c"}
]
 
const getUniqArrBy = (props = [], arrInp = [], objTmp={}, arrTmp=[]) => {
  if (arrInp.length > 0) {
    const lastItem = arrInp[arrInp.length -1]
    const propStr = props.reduce((res, item) => (`${res}${lastItem[item]}`), '')
    if (!objTmp[propStr]) {
      objTmp[propStr] = true
      arrTmp=[...arrTmp, lastItem]
    }
    arrInp.pop()
    return getUniqArrBy(props, arrInp, objTmp, arrTmp)
  }
  return arrTmp
}

const uniq = getUniqArrBy(['class', 'fare'], arr)

console.info({ uniq })
/*
    [
      {class: "first", fare: "c"},
      {class: "second", fare: "a"},
      {class: "first", fare: "a"},
      {class: "second", fare: "b"},
    ]
*/
```

**1.5% lags behind the first one by performance**

```js
const arr = [{class:"second", fare: "a"}, 
 {class:"second", fare: "b"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"second", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "c"}
]
 
const getUniqArrBy = (props = [], arrInp = []) => {
  const objKey = {}
  return arrInp.reduce((res, item) => {
    const valStr = props.reduce((res, prop) => `${res}${item[prop]}`, '')
    if(objKey[valStr]) return res
    objKey[valStr] = item
    return [...res, item]
  }, [])
}

const uniq = getUniqArrBy(['class', 'fare'], arr)

console.info({ uniq })
/*
    [
     {class:"second", fare: "a"},
     {class:"second", fare: "b"},
     {class:"first", fare: "a"},
     {class:"first", fare: "c"}
    ]
*/
```

**Close to the fist two ones by performance**

```js
const arr = [{class:"second", fare: "a"}, 
 {class:"second", fare: "b"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"second", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "c"}
]

const getUniqArrBy = (props = [], arr = []) => arr.filter((e, i) =>
   arr.findIndex(a => {
    let aKey = '', eKey = ''
    props.forEach(prop => (aKey = `${aKey}${a[prop]}`, eKey = `${eKey}${e[prop]}`))
    return aKey === eKey
}) === i)

const uniq = getUniqArrBy(['class', 'fare'], arr)

console.info({ uniq })
/*
[
 {class:"second", fare: "a"},
 {class:"second", fare: "b"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "c"}
]
*/
```

**In Firefox works fast, in Chrome and Edge - not, short by notation**

```js
const arr = [{class:"second", fare: "a"}, 
 {class:"second", fare: "b"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"second", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "c"}
]
 
const getUniqArrBy = (props = [], arrInp = []) => {
  return Object.values(arrInp.reduce((res, item) => {
    const keyComb = props.reduce((res, prop) => `${res}${item[prop]}`, '')
    return { ...res, [keyComb]: item }
  }, []))
}

const uniq = getUniqArrBy(['class', 'fare'], arr)

console.info({ uniq })
/*
    [
     {class:"second", fare: "a"},
     {class:"second", fare: "b"},
     {class:"first", fare: "a"},
     {class:"first", fare: "c"}
    ]
*/
```

***The short by notation, but usually a 5-8% slower then the first***

```js
const arr = [{class:"second", fare: "a"}, 
 {class:"second", fare: "b"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"second", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "c"}
]

const getUniqArrBy = (props = [], arr = []) => arr.filter((e, i) =>
   arr.findIndex(a => props.reduce((res, prop) => `${res}${a[prop]}`, '') ===
   props.reduce((res, prop) => `${res}${e[prop]}`, '')) === i)

const uniq = getUniqArrBy(['class', 'fare'], arr)

console.info({ uniq })
/*
    [
     {class:"second", fare: "a"},
     {class:"second", fare: "b"},
     {class:"first", fare: "a"},
     {class:"first", fare: "c"}
    ]
*/
```

**A slower by 9-18% than the first in average in different browsers**

```js
const arr = [{class:"second", fare: "a"}, 
 {class:"second", fare: "b"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "a"},
 {class:"second", fare: "a"},
 {class:"first", fare: "c"}
]
 
const getUniqArrBy = (props = [], arrInp = []) => {
  const objKey = arrInp.reduce((res, item) => {
    const valStr = props.reduce((res, prop) => `${res}${item[prop]}`, '')
    return {...res, [valStr]: item }
  }, {})
  return Object.keys(objKey).map(item => objKey[item])
}

const uniq = getUniqArrBy(['class', 'fare'], arr)

console.info({ uniq })
/*
    [
     {class:"second", fare: "a"},
     {class:"second", fare: "b"},
     {class:"first", fare: "a"},
     {class:"first", fare: "c"}
    ]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function unique(arr, keyProps) {
 const kvArray = arr.map(entry => { // entry = {class: "second", fare: "a"}

  // keyProps = ["class", "fare"]
  // k="class"; entry[k]="second";
  // k="fare"; entry[k]="a"
  // keyProps.map(k => entry[k])=["second","a"];
  // .join("|")="second|a";
  const key = keyProps.map(k => entry[k]).join('|'); // key = "second|a"
  return [key, entry]; // ["second|a",{"class":"second","fare":"a"}]
 });

 // kvArray = [["second|a",{"class":"second","fare":"a"}],["second|b", 
 //           {"class":"second","fare":"b"}],["first|a",{"class":"first","fare":"a"}], 
 //           ["first|a",{"class":"first","fare":"a"}],["second|a", 
 //           {"class":"second","fare":"a"}],["first|c",{"class":"first","fare":"c"}]]
 const map = new Map(kvArray); // this will remove duplicate entry with same key. 
 return Array.from(map.values()); // convert back to array from all entry's value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation of extracting a unique array of objects based on arbitrary array of their fields:

```js
    const arr = [
      { class: 'second', fare: 'a', weight: 12 },
      { class: 'second', fare: 'b', weight: 10 },
      { class: 'first', fare: 'a', weight: 15 },
      { class: 'first', fare: 'a', weight: 17 },
      { class: 'second', fare: 'a', weight: 12 },
      { class: 'first', fare: 'c', weight: 30 },
      { class: 'second', fare: 'b', weight: 22 },
    ]

    const getUniqArrBy = (props = [], arrInp = [{}]) => {
      const obj = {}
      let result = []
      arrInp.forEach((item, index) => {
            let key = ''
            props.forEach(prop => (key += item[prop]))
            obj[key] = index
      })
      const keys = Object.keys(obj)
      keys.forEach(key => (result = [...result, arrInp[obj[key]]]))
      return result
    }

    const uniq = getUniqArrBy(['class', 'fare'], arr)

    console.info({ uniq })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` to loop and `filter` or `find` array property to find if the element exist in array

```
var arr = [{
      class: "second",
      fare: "a"
    }, {
      class: "second",
      fare: "b"
    }, {
      class: "first",
      fare: "a"
    }, {
      class: "first",
      fare: "a"
    }, {
      class: "second",
      fare: "a"
    }, {
      class: "first",
      fare: "c"
    }]
    var _unArray = []; // new array without duplicate
    arr.forEach(function(item) { // loop through array which contain duplicate
      // if item is not found in _unArray it will return empty array
       var isPresent = _unArray.filter(function(elem) {
        return elem.class === item.class && elem.fare === item.fare
      })
      if (isPresent.length == 0) { 
        _unArray.push(item)
      }
    })
    console.log(_unArray)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/jpwve5z9/)

Comment: It is unsatisfying for the solution to have the properties `class` and `fare` baked into it.