# how to filter array for unique id in typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of object, how to filter array for unique id in typescript/javascript

list array -

```
[{
    global_id: "269a8bded9bd4ecaa0e501c170a71f5a"
    icon: "/odb/icons/ip/ip_32.svg"
    id: "269a8bded9bd4ecaa0e501c170a71f5a"
}, {
    global_id: "269a8bded9bd4ecaa0e501c170a71f5a"
    icon: "/odb/icons/ip/ip_32.svg"
    id: "269a8bded9bd4ecaa0e501c170a71f5a"
}, {
    global_id: 348
    icon: "/odb/icons/ip/ip_32.svg"
    id: 348
}, {
    global_id: 201
    icon: "/odb/icons/ip/ip_32.svg"
    id: 201
}]
```

so on,

I want to filter my array of object in such a way not duplicate element should list.

`list.filter()` i want to use if i can.

`_.uniqBy(list, 'id');` is available in lodash but i want to use typescript/javascrpt .filter method.
Please guide.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120931/how-to-count-the-number-of-certain-element-in-an-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create array of unique objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773778/create-array-of-unique-objects-by-property) and [javascript - find unique objects in array based on multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613654)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a soluce using Array.filter

```js
function uniqueArrayOfObject(array, keyToBeUnique) {
  // Filter by looking at the next objects if the key is present a second time
  return array.filter((x, xi) => !array.slice(xi + 1)
    .some(y => y[keyToBeUnique] === x[keyToBeUnique]));
}

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

const keys = [
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
];

const generatedArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1) {
  generatedArray.push({
    uniqueKey: keys[getRndInteger(0, keys.length - 1)],
    val: i,
  });
}

const start = Date.now();

const unique = uniqueArrayOfObject(generatedArray, 'uniqueKey');

console.log(unique);

console.log(`It took ${Date.now() - start}ms to unique`);
```

---

Other soluce (quicker)

```js
function uniqueArrayOfObject(array, keyToBeUnique) {
  return Object.values(array.reduce((tmp, x) => {
    // You already get a value
    if (tmp[x[keyToBeUnique]]) return tmp;

    // You never envcountered this key
    tmp[x[keyToBeUnique]] = x;

    return tmp;
  }, {}));
}

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

const keys = [
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
];

const generatedArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1) {
  generatedArray.push({
    uniqueKey: keys[getRndInteger(0, keys.length - 1)],
    val: i,
  });
}

const start = Date.now();

const unique = uniqueArrayOfObject(generatedArray, 'uniqueKey');

console.log(unique);

console.log(`It took ${Date.now() - start}ms to unique`);
```

Comment: if array is not sorted, we have to sort and do this.

Comment: If the values behind the global_id are the same you don't have to sort. If they are not, yes you have to. Or you could use a function that will determine which one to keep

Comment: I have an array count of 10000 list is it the best approach with respect to performance. Please guide.

Comment: I've edited my post with a quicker soluce

Answer (score 3):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
var data =[{global_id:"269a8bded9bd4ecaa0e501c170a71f5a",icon:"/odb/icons/ip/ip_32.svg",id:"269a8bded9bd4ecaa0e501c170a71f5a"},{global_id:"269a8bded9bd4ecaa0e501c170a71f5a",icon:"/odb/icons/ip/ip_32.svg",id:"269a8bded9bd4ecaa0e501c170a71f5a"},{global_id:348,icon:"/odb/icons/ip/ip_32.svg",id:348},{global_id:201,icon:"/odb/icons/ip/ip_32.svg",id:201}];

const res = [...data.reduce((a,c)=>{
  a.set(c.global_id, c);
  return a;
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(res);
```

---

Performance

```js
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

const keys = [
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
];

const generatedArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1) {
  generatedArray.push({
    global_id: keys[getRndInteger(0, keys.length - 1)],
    val: i,
  });
}

const start = Date.now();

const unique = [...generatedArray.reduce((a,c)=>{
  a.set(c.global_id, c);
  return a;
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(unique);

console.log(`It took ${Date.now() - start}ms to unique`);
```

Comment: its gives error while using, says type iterableiterator is not array type. use compiler option it says.

Comment: @JavascriptCoder that's probably because you need to specify a higher ECMAScript version in your .tsconfig file (or webpack.config.js or .babelrc depending on your setup). Might need to try es2016 or es2017 or es2018.