# Selecting unique items in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, unique

Assuming I have the following array of objects

```
[{a:1,b:2,c:4}, {a:3,b:4,c:7}, {a:7,b:10,c:10}, {a:1, b:2,c:4}]
```

How do I select the unique items in this array.  I need to compare both fields (a, b only, excluding c) and the examples I have seen show a map which takes a single field only.

Comment: So your expected output is `{a:3,b:4,c:7}, {a:7,b:10,c:10}`?

Comment: Can you please tell your expected output?

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613654/javascript-find-unique-objects-in-array-based-on-multiple-properties

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested filter, and check that the number of matching elements with the same `a` and `b` is 1:

```js
const input = [{a:1,b:2,c:4}, {a:3,b:4,c:7}, {a:7,b:10,c:10}, {a:1, b:2,c:4}];
const output = input.filter(
  ({ a, b }) => input.filter(obj => obj.a === a && obj.b === b).length === 1
);
console.log(output);
```

For `O(N)` complexity instead, reduce into an object indexed by `num_num`, or something like that, and then select only the values which have one item in them:

```js
const input = [{a:1,b:2,c:4}, {a:3,b:4,c:7}, {a:7,b:10,c:10}, {a:1, b:2,c:4}];
const inputByAB = input.reduce((accum, obj) => {
  const key = `${obj.a}_${obj.b}`;
  if (!accum[key]) {
    accum[key] = [];
  }
  accum[key].push(obj);
  return accum;
}, {});
const output = Object.values(inputByAB)
  .filter(arr => arr.length === 1)
  .flat();
console.log(output);
```

If you can't use `.flat`, spread into concat instead:

```js
const input = [{a:1,b:2,c:4}, {a:3,b:4,c:7}, {a:7,b:10,c:10}, {a:1, b:2,c:4}];
const inputByAB = input.reduce((accum, obj) => {
  const key = `${obj.a}_${obj.b}`;
  if (!accum[key]) {
    accum[key] = [];
  }
  accum[key].push(obj);
  return accum;
}, {});
const output = [].concat(...
  Object.values(inputByAB)
    .filter(arr => arr.length === 1)
);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic keys create a function which takes array and arrays strings representing keys as input.

Create another helper method which compare the given keys of two objects.

Use `filter()` on the array of objects and then use `every()` element before the current index is not equal to the current object regarding given keys.

```js
let arr = [{a:1,b:2,c:4}, {a:3,b:4,c:7}, {a:7,b:10,c:10}, {a:1, b:2,c:4}];
function comp(obj1,obj2,keys){
  return keys.every(k => obj1[k] === obj2[k]);
}
function getUnique(arr,keys){
  return arr.filter((x,i) => arr.slice(0,i).every(a => !comp(a,x,keys)))
}

console.log(getUnique(arr,['a','b']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as an accumulator. Use a combination of `a` and `b` properties as key so that duplicates are removed. Then use [`Map#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) to get the output

```js
const input = [{a:1,b:2,c:4}, {a:3,b:4,c:7}, {a:7,b:10,c:10}, {a:1, b:2,c:4}],
      mapped = input.reduce((map, o) => map.set(o.a + "_" + o.b, o), new Map),
      output = Array.from(mapped.values());

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, I think I forgot to mention, I also need the a single item of the duplicated item, not to completely ignore them.  The sample code give above removes the duplicates completely, I need one instance of it.

Comment: @tmpdev It doesn't remove the duplicates completely. It keeps one item for every unique `a` and `b`. The output has 3 items. Only one item with `a:1,b:2` is in the output

Comment: @tmpdev if this answers you question, please upvote and mark it as accepted.