# How to make object which store unique key have multiple different values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
    var data = [{type: 'physical', value: 'verified'}, 
                {type: 'reference', value: 'owner'},
                {type: 'physical', value: 'pending'},
                {type: 'document', value: 'pending'}
               ]
```

How to return object in such a way which should have unique key which store mulpltiple values

Expected Result =

```
  var data  = {
      physical: ['verified', 'pending'],
      reference: ['owner'],
      document: ['pending']
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript - find unique objects in array based on multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613654/javascript-find-unique-objects-in-array-based-on-multiple-properties)

Comment: Please share the expected results based on the data you supplied.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Even if it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Expected result =
```var data  = {
      physical: ['verified', 'pending'],
      reference: ['owner'],
      document: ['pending']
  }```

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I tried but didn't work for me with this code
`var hashMap = {}
for (const i of data) {
    hashMap[i.type] = i
  }
  return hashMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function should return the result as you asked.

```
function getUnique(data){
    let x = {};
    for(let i of data){
        if (!x[i.type]){x[i.type] = [];}
        x[i.type].push(i.value);
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the data array to an object and build the properties as well as the values in each property using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing).

```
data.reduce((acc, { type, value }) => ({
    ...acc,
    [type]: [...(acc[type] ?? []), value]
}), {});
```