# Get unique items from array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

i have an array

```
friendList = [
              {id: 1, fName: 'Sam', lName: 'Brian', profilePic: 'sam.jpg'},
              {id: 2, fName: 'Dam', lName: 'Nary', profilePic: 'dam.jpg'},
              {id: 3, fName: 'Jam', lName: 'kent', profilePic: 'jam.jpg'},
              {id: 1, fName: 'Sam', lName: 'Brian', profilePic: 'sam.jpg'},
              {id: 3, fName: 'Jam', lName: 'kent', profilePic: 'jam.jpg'}, 
             ]
```

how can i get a unique array of this friendList.. such that the result is :

```
friendList = [
              {id: 1, fName: 'Sam', lName: 'Brian', profilePic: 'sam.jpg'},
              {id: 2, fName: 'Dam', lName: 'Nary', profilePic: 'dam.jpg'},
              {id: 3, fName: 'Jam', lName: 'kent', profilePic: 'jam.jpg'}
             ]
```

Comment: [No, they are not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773778/create-array-of-unique-objects-by-property).

Comment: var uniqueArry = Object.values(friendList.reduce((acc,ele)=>{return {...acc,...{[ele.id]:ele}}},{}))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `friendList` items should be filtered by unique `id` property, you can make use of the fact that object should have unique keys.

With that in mind, you may

- traverse your source array using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and build up an object, having `id` as a key and corresponding item object as a value
- extract [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) into array of unique records

Following is a proof of a concept live-demo:

```js
const friendList = [{id:1,fName:'Sam',lName:'Brian',profilePic:'sam.jpg'},{id:2,fName:'Dam',lName:'Nary',profilePic:'dam.jpg'},{id:3,fName:'Jam',lName:'kent',profilePic:'jam.jpg'},{id:1,fName:'Sam',lName:'Brian',profilePic:'sam.jpg'},{id:3,fName:'Jam',lName:'kent',profilePic:'jam.jpg'},],
             
      friendListMap = friendList.reduce((r,item) => 
        (r[item.id] = item, r), {}),
        
      dedupeFriendList = Object.values(friendListMap)
      
console.log(dedupeFriendList)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```