# Getting keys from associative array in javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In javascript (or CoffeScript) is there a way to just get the keys for a associative array? The real problem I am trying to solve is to create a set but the only way I found that is to create a map and use the keys to produce the set. I know I can iterate over the elements and collect them but that seems like extra work to me.

So for example in CoffeeScript I could do:

```
foobar = { "a": true, "b": true, "c": true }
keys = []
keys.push k for k,v of foobar
```

Which honestly isn't that much code but is there really no other way to do a set or just get the keys from an associative array without writing a special class or pulling in a separate library?

UPDATE: I have a requirement that IE < 9 needs to be supported so unfortunately Object.keys(foobar) is out. Good suggestion though, sorry I missed this req in the original question.

Comment: keys=Object.keys(foobar)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys There is a IE6+ polyfill too.

Comment: Do note for a tip: Object.keys not available for IE < 9

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that i'd seen Object.keys before. Unfortunately IE < 9 is a requirement.

Comment: You may want to see this code for mimicking some set-like functionality in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript/7958422#7958422

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) (or their respective shims), coffeescript offers very nice [loop comprehensions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

```
keys = (k for own k of foobar) // == Object.keys foobar
keys = (k for k of foobar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and the polyfill here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys for browsers that don't support that.