# adding a set of sets in a key value pair array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array, key-value

I have a simple function declared like this:

```
foo(data){
    ....
}
```

I am trying to call the function by sending it a key value like so:

```
foo({
    A : {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
});
```

---

**But I keep getting the following error from my ide (netbeans)**

```
Expected indent but found {
        A : {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
             ^

Expected an operand but found ,
        A : {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
                   ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get the `{1, 2}` syntax from? That doesn't exist in JS. Arrays: `[1,2,3]`, objects: `{foo: 42}`. I recommend to read a tutorial to learn about basic JS syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Creating_an_Array, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers

Comment: FYI, if you want an object that implements sets in javascript, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript/7958422#7958422).

Answer (score 0):

`A : {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`
doesn't make any sense. In JavaScript `{}` creates a key-value store, also known as a JavaScript object. Every element inside of a JavaScript object must be a key-value pair. To store a simple list/array, use `[]`

```
foo({
    A : [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
});
```

Comment: `[{1, 2}, {3, 4}]` doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. *facepalm*

Comment: yes thanks It works, I thought `{}` was a set syntax and `[]` was a list. My bad

Comment: @Krimson: Sets don't exist in JS (at least not yet).