# Pop up alert messages in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code should pop up an alert if radio button is not selected.
  My problem is that it only pops up if you have choosen one question. For example, i selected an answer in question 1 but not on question 2. So it gives an alert: Must select question number two! But my problem is that, if you don't select any, it doesn't alert me anything. If i haven't selected anything, it should pop up, 2 alerts, Must select question number one and after that, another alert, must select question number 2! any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>


    function checkAnswers(){
    var retval = false;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){

        var inputName = inputs[i].getAttribute('name'); 
  //      var msg = document.getElementById('msg-' + inputName);
                var checker = document.getElementsByName(inputName);
                var counter = false;
                for(j=0;j<checker.length;j++){
                    if(checker[j].checked == true){
                    counter = true;
                    i += 4;
                    break;
                    }
                }
                if(counter == false){
                    alert("Must answer question number" + " " + inputName + "!");
                    retval = false;
                    i += 4;
                }
        }
        return retval;

}

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return checkAnswers()" id="form">
        <h1>QUESTIONS</h1>
        <h3>Question No. 1.)</h3>What makes you smile?<br />
        <input name="one" type="radio" value="yes"  />A. Burger<br />
        <input name="one" type="radio" value="no" />B. Pizza <br />
        <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  />C.Sunrise <br />
        <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat<br />
        <span id="msg-one"></span><br />


            <h3>Question No. 2.)</h3>What's your favorite day?<br />
        <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />A. Hi<br />
        <input name="two" type="radio" value="yes"  />B. Hello<br />
        <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />C. Ahh<br />
        <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat<br />
        <span id="msg-two"></span><br/>


            <input type="button" name='submit' value="Submit"  /><br />
            <span id="score"></span><br />
    </form>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use boolean statements?

Comment: tried your code at my side, it seems to work, only had to change the button from button type to submit type and got 2 alerts

Comment: hey, i have another question. how can you hightlight the question number you have not selected?

Answer (score 0):

You have nested for loops, both using the variable "i". Try changing this so each loop has an individual (ideally descriptive) variable name.

Comment: i tried but did not work if i haven't selected any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you added [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I'll suggest a solution using jQuery:

```
function checkAnswers() {
    var questions = {};
    $('#form input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
        // add all questions
        questions[this.name] = true;
    }).filter(":checked").each(function() {
        // remove questions that have an answer
        delete questions[this.name];
    });
    for (var k in questions) {
        alert("Must answer question number " + k + "!");
    }
}
```

`questions` is used here [to mimic a set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7958422/2991525).

But your submit button also should have the type `submit`, not `button` or you need to add a `onclick` handler:

```
<input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit"  />
```