# Difference between documents returned from Two MongoDB queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and NoSQL and have the following query:
I have the following documents in a sample MongoDB Collection

```
Data Collection

{ "Name" : "A",
  "date" : "2015-04-29"
},
{ "Name" : "B",
  "date" : "2015-04-29"
},
{ "Name" : "A",
  "date" : "2015-04-30"
}
```

I want to run a query on the comparing the dates trying to find out which name was not present on date = "2015-04-30" but was present on date = "2015-04-29".

```
The result of the above query would be :
{ "Name" : "B" }
```

Basically trying to compare results from two mongodb queries and then showing a result. 
Please let me know if this would be possible to do.

Comment: Is your `date` data type `string` or `ISODate` ?

Comment: date data type is ISODate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [aggregation pipeline operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/). First you will need to group your document by `Name` using [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group). The [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) is a accumulator operator that let you create and array of `date` field. Use [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) to field document with given criteria.

```js
db.data.aggregate(
    [
        { "$group": { "_id": "$Name", "date": { "$push": "$date" }}},
        { "$match": { "date": { "$not": { "$all": ["2015-04-29", "2015-04-30" ]}}}}, 
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would achieve it with sets.

First take the elements that you are interested in:
`var need = db.a.distinct('Name', {date: '2015-04-29'})`

take the element that you are not interested:
`var doNotNeed = db.a.distinct('Name', {date: '2015-04-30'})`

Now if you subtract the `set(need)` with `set(doNotNeed)`, you will get your answers. Mongoshell does not support [sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27588953/1090562), but you can use dictionaries:

```
var needSet = {}
for (var i=0; i < need.length; i++){
  needSet[need[i]] = 1;
}

for (var i=0; i < doNotNeed.length; i++){
  if (doNotNeed[i] in needSet){
     delete needSet[doNotNeed[i]]
  } 
}
```

needSet would have all the elements that satisfy your query. You can get them by calling `Object.keys(needSet)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, try this snippet

```js
var arr=[];

db.Collection.find({"date":"2015-04-30"}).forEach(function(item){
var val=item.Name;

var found=db.Collection.findOne({"date":"2015-04-29","Name":val});

if (!found)
  arr.push(val);

});

printjson(arr);
```