# Check if Filename Already Exists in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I check if a certain file name already exists in my array? For example, on initial load, I get some files from the server:

```
var initialFiles = ['file1_1','file2_0','file3_3','file4_2','file5_6'];
```

I push them to an array and set in sessionStorage:

```
filesArray.push(initialFiles);
sessionStorage.setItem('file-names', JSON.stringify(filesArray));
```

Then after a user interacts with the site, I get more files:

```
var newFiles = ['file1_1', 'file2_0', 'file1_2', 'file3_5', 'file4_6'];
```

You can see that `file1_1` and `file2_0` have already been loaded. How do I NOT add those file names in the array?

See an example here: http://jsbin.com/hiyefexudi/edit?html,js,console

Comment: `[].indexOf()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ES6 semantics (modern browser, transpiled code or latest node.js), you can more efficiently use a `Set` object which will automatically keep duplicates out.

```
 var files = new Set(['file1_1','file2_0','file3_3','file4_2','file5_6']);
 var newFiles = ['file1_1', 'file2_0', 'file1_2', 'file3_5', 'file4_6'];
 files.add(...newFiles);

 sessionStorage.setItem('file-names', JSON.stringify(Array.from(files)));
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7d1dy1p7/

[MDN reference on the Set object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

---

And, there are numerous polyfills for the Set object too as it is a generally useful concept, particularly for things like this.  Here's one I've created: [Mimicking sets in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript/7958422#7958422)

---

Or, if you're trying to find out which items in the `newFiles` list are actually new and not in the `files` list already, then you can do that like this.

```
 var files = new Set(['file1_1','file2_0','file3_3','file4_2','file5_6']);
 var newFiles = ['file1_1', 'file2_0', 'file1_2', 'file3_5', 'file4_6'];

 var uniqueNewFiles = newFiles.filter(function(item) {
     return !files.has(item);
 });
```

Then, afterwards to update the existing files list, you can add these to it:

```
 files.add(...uniqueNewFiles);
```

---

Or, using a more capable [Set object](https://github.com/jfriend00/Javascript-Set/blob/master/set.js), you could do this:

```
 var files = new Set(['file1_1','file2_0','file3_3','file4_2','file5_6']);
 var newFiles = new Set(['file1_1', 'file2_0', 'file1_2', 'file3_5', 'file4_6']);

  var uniqueNewFiles = newFiles.difference(files);
```

Comment: Hmm ok. How would this work if the `files` array kept on updating? So in this case you have 1 array that updates everytime, but I want to only store the new files in `sessionStorage`.

Comment: OK, I did not understand that was your question.  A `Set` object is still useful for that.  I've added a couple examples of using a `Set` object for that purpose.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will test this out and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if each file in the new array is in the old one using indexOf == -1

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L42h7uhm/

```
var initialFiles = ['file1_1', 'file2_0', 'file3_3', 'file4_2', 'file5_6'];

var newFiles = ['file1_1', 'file2_0', 'file1_2', 'file3_5', 'file4_6'];

newFiles.forEach(function (file) {
    console.log(initialFiles.indexOf(file) == -1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate both arrays and filter out non-unique items.

```
var initialFiles = ['file1_1', 'file2_0', 'file3_3', 'file4_2', 'file5_6'];

var newFiles = ['file1_1', 'file2_0', 'file1_2', 'file3_5', 'file4_6'];

var newArray = initialFiles.concat(newFiles);

var uniqueArray = newArray.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return newArray.indexOf(item) == pos;
});

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this solution.

Comment: @mapr - This is not particularly efficient.  Add all the duplicates (creating a new array while doing so), then create a new array by filtering that involves searching through the array for every item in the array, one at a time, even the items that were already dup-free.  The `Set` object, either from ES6 or from a polyfill is the preferred design pattern for lists of items with no dups.

Comment: @jfriend00 Not efficient due to speed?

Comment: @mapr - Yes, slower and inefficient from a memory usage and garbage collection point of view.  But, with small numbers of items in the list, you probably wouldn't notice a performance difference.  Mostly, it's just an inefficient design pattern to create two new arrays (one with `.concat()` and one with `.filter()` when all you want to do is add some non-dups to the original.  The `Set` object is built exactly for that task, so I'm trying to teach a more appropriate design pattern for this type of problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, that makes sense. Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. Extremely helpful.