# Generic Typescript function to check for duplicates in an array

Tags: arrays, typescript, duplicates, typescript-generics

I'm trying make a generic Typescript function to check if an array contains duplicates. For example:

```
interface Student {
  name: string;
  class: string;
};

const students: Student[] = [
  { name: 'John Smith', class: 'Science' },
  { name: 'Edward Ryan', class: 'Math' },
  { name: 'Jessica Li', class: 'Social Studies'},
  { name: 'John Smith', class: 'English'}
];
```

That is the data.

This is what I want to do with the data:

```
const registerStudents = async (students: Student[]): Promise<void> {
  
  checkDuplicate(students, existingState); //This is the function I want to build

  const response = await axios.post('/students/new', students)
  existingState.push(response); //pushes newly registers students to the existing state
};
```

Regarding the `checkDuplicate()`, I want to make it a generic function, but I'm struggling with the logic.

```
export const checkDuplicate = <T>(items: T[], existingState: T[]): void {
  //checks if the items have any duplicate names, in this case, it would be 'John Smith', and if so, throw an error

  //Also checks if items have any duplicate names with the existingState of the application, and if so, throw an error

  if (duplicate) {
    throw new Error('contains identical information')
  };
};
```

It's a little bit complex and I haven't been able to figure out the logic to work with typescript. Any advice on how I can implement this would be appreciated!

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQKnvm) meet your needs?  If so, I could write up an answer.  If not, could you explain how you'd implement `checkDuplicate()` in pure JavaScript or if it were not generic?  Then I could maybe give it types.

Comment: Oh wow this is perfect, I need to take sometime to understand this code but it works perfectly.

Comment: Okay then I will write up an answer with an explanation when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reasonable way to approach this is to have `checkDuplicate()` take a single array `items` of generic type `T[]`, and another array `keysToCheck` of type `K[]`, where `K` is a keylike type (or [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keylike types) and where `T` is a type with keys in `K` and whose values at those keys are `string`s.  That is, the call signature of `checkDuplicate()` should be

```
declare const checkDuplicate: <T extends Record<K, string>, K extends PropertyKey>(
    items: T[],
    keysToCheck: K[]
) => void;
```

This function should iterate over both `items` and `keysToCheck`, and if it finds an item where a property is the same string as the same property in a previous item, it should throw an error.

If you had such a function, you could write the version which accepts `students` and `existingState`, two arrays of `Student` objects, like this:

```
function checkDuplicateStudents(students: Student[], existingState: Student[]) {
    checkDuplicate([...students, ...existingState], ["name", "class"]);
}
```

where we are [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the `students` and `existingState` arrays into a single array to pass as `items` to `checkDuplicate()`, and since we are checking `Student` we are passing `["name", "class"]` as `keysToCheck`.

---

Here's a possible implementation of `checkDuplicate()`:

```
const checkDuplicate = <T extends Record<K, string>, K extends PropertyKey>(
    items: T[],
    keysToCheck: K[]
): void => {
    const vals = {} as Record<K, Set<string>>;
    keysToCheck.forEach(key => vals[key] = new Set());
    for (let item of items) {
        for (let key of keysToCheck) {
            const val: string = item[key];
            const valSet: Set<string> = vals[key]
            if (valSet.has(val)) {
                throw new Error(
                    'contains identical information at key "' +
                    key + '" with value "' + val + '"');
            };
            valSet.add(val);
        }
    }
}
```

The way it works is that we create an object named `vals` with one key for each element `key` of `keysToCheck`.  Each element `vals[key]` is the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of strings we have already seen for that `key`.  Every time we see a `string`-valued property `val` with key `key` in any `item` in the `items` array, we check whether the set in `vals[key]` has `val`.  If so, we've seen this value for this key before, so we throw an error.  If not, we add it to the set.

(Note that it's possible to replace `Set<string>` with a plain object of the form `Record<string, true | undefined>`, as shown in [Mimicking sets in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958292/mimicking-sets-in-javascript/7958422#7958422) , but I'm using `Set` here for clarity.)

---

Okay, let's test it against your example:

```
checkDuplicateStudents(students, []);
// contains identical information at key "name" with value "John Smith"
```

Looks good.  It throws an error at runtime and properly identifies the duplicate data.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4BMLmQbwFgAoZM5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4TzkEAbOBg3pMWIDiQC+nYiQQB7EE0aYc4IWhW4wAbQC6yALzJtXcvgrU6yAOQApOQAsQaKsDAPrAGh79B9a6gIwLhI1sgSnqZk5pQ0-gCiWADucFBYyABKAJ5wIF4+AurWALJw7mERUQQWcTa2EILACHDIADLA+XyF-qhyQXC8GtjBDBWRpGY1VnaOzqiu5d5dfjbxYrzADB7hJLrSJLIKSggOEAgA1gAiGAAOG82QhsgAPAAqyBAAHpAgWAyZZzkaWeAGlvCI2AA+bwgj7fXB-ZAABSgchu0DAWRBECykIAFFU3BAqOpXnpxtxzjiGK85ABhU4XeggvQkACU9AAbnJgOkDJCCFV5IowMhOQN-kZ8BJkAIAfJgWC0BAwM8IWJIZDpJTqbSGWdzgA6GBA+KIBx4qlZQwC8W8BjaK36IwgCBJZVgPFstna8gmqDIPG8FXIIlUZByGChyAktmCibcMj+wPB0VWiNRq00+mM85xogJxPcYVKO3CZhsJ5hx04vZVItkEuiu2oFX0Vuq9WsAVGO0Op31hvAKN4lsqw0OASjgbe+MN+fIdyo92u93xKCoqAEwsLhvWYVgOCgf68rRNAahkD+qhlYAKWVpnHIABEYQA1IPdzrrW+bM-kEkbgOGKAwYCgr7IL+dqQX+1g+p+iZSAh3BjmAhpwFgWDTrw8E7uQEhVARxBESQAD0ABUJA4F0UAoE2PC5tcdznpA9BvHCPyIhkgKKuCFYajCHEIv8KJohiWI4vihIxqS5JVFmeq5syrLEHG-JijyWDSORpEHMQMAYCACBgHezgnAaTH3GUEDoNgWgMHiTB2Wo7aaOA5JwpsJliOg1muc5Oi6PmQqMbcVmQHi2iGtFTmqGADDeNFhpfF5bC+ZAujeNoz6xBAz7eM+ywMM+QXSCRxDmRclksTZbnxY5dUJcYpVkaRPAKIex6hnF56DKA163veZTIOmOWWP+gHuCBvBgS+9hOC4QHPnpJBAA)

Comment: Great answer and thanks for taking the time to explain your logic!