# How to Remove Duplicates From Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here I have two multiline textboxes and enter some data in two textboxes like
txt1
1,1,1,2,2,2,3
txt2
1,2,3,4,5,
when i press Filter button it shows the data in thirdtextbox like
txt3
4,5 (both the textboxes are having these numbers)
My snippet is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetDistinctElements(source,source1, target) {           
        var input = source.value.trim().replace(';', ',').split(',');
        var input1 = source1.value.trim().replace(';', ',').split(',');           
        var Array = input.concat(input1);
        var distinctArray = Array.filter(function (item, pos) {              
            return Array.indexOf(item) == pos;
        });           
        target.value = distinctArray.join(',');
    }
</script>
```

and my controls are

```
<table border="0" align="left">
    <tr>
        <td>Enter Numbers:</td>
        <td> <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td>Enter Numbers:</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt2" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='button' value='Get Distinct Items' onclick='GetDistinctElements(<%= txt1.ClientID %>,<%= txt2.ClientID %>,<%= txt3.ClientID %>); return false;' /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt3" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when I tried this snippet, I didn`t get the expected output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343746/is-there-a-data-structure-like-the-java-set-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523436/javascript-implementation-of-a-set-data-structure

Comment: *"I didn`t get the expected output."* - You could be a bit clearer about what the expected output actually is. And did you get some other output instead, or an error in your browser's dev console?

Comment: txt1: 1,1,1,2,2,2,3 txt2: 1,2,3,4,5, when i press Filter button it shows the data in thirdtextbox like txt3: 1,2,3 (both the textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer

```
 function GetDistinctElements(source,source1, target) {
        // Get the items in your input
        var input = source.value.trim().replace(';', ',').split(',');
        var input1 = source1.value.trim().replace(';', ',').split(',');           
        input1 = input1.filter(function (val) {
            return input.indexOf(val) == -1;
        });
        // Output the result in  target area
        target.value = input1.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
var Array = input.concat(input1);
var distinctArray = Array.filter(function (item, pos) {              
    return Array.indexOf(item) == pos;
});
```

by this:

```
var input2 = input.concat(input1);
input2.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
var prev= null;
var distinctArray = input2.filter(function (item, pos) {              
    if (item == prev){
      return false;
    }
    prev = item;
    return true;
});
```

Comment: ,thanks for your reply...but it shows two textboxes values in third textbox like t1:1,2,3.t2:1,3,4,5 t3:1,2,3,1,3,4,5

Comment: fixed that with adding `input2.sort();`